# big query BadRequest: 400 Unrecognized name after running a query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm running a BQ query using Python. I am trying to pull the listed columns. The date format is yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 so I changed it to the needed date format. It works fine but the issue I'm having is with my WHERE statement. What I am trying to do is to just pull the last 7 days of my data.

The error is the following:
`BadRequest: 400 Unrecognized name: date at [4:10]`

Could someone point me in the right direction of where the mistake is coming from?

```
query_job = client.query(f"""
   SELECT sku, sku_unit_count, entity_id, revenue, CAST(order_date AS DATE) as date, 
   unique_code, refunds
   FROM tables.revenue
   WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
   LIMIT 5; """)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
query_job = client.query(f"""
   SELECT sku, sku_unit_count, entity_id, revenue, CAST(order_date AS DATE) as date, 
   unique_code, refunds
   FROM tables.revenue
   WHERE CAST(order_date AS DATE) >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
   LIMIT 5; """)
```